# imagick, is not installed, or has been disabled

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform

I'm getting this error in the **WordPress Site Health Status**, and I found that this could related with the hosting service, my website hosted in Google Cloud service:

> "PHP modules perform most of the tasks on the server that make your
> site run. Any changes to these must be made by your server
> administrator.
>
> The WordPress Hosting Team maintains a list of those modules, both
> recommended and required, in the team handbook (opens in a new tab).
>
> Warning The optional module, imagick, is not installed, or has been
> disabled. Warning The optional module, zip, is not installed, or has
> been disabled."

Did anybody already experienced something similar and managed to fix it ?

Comment: Do you have root access to the server?

Comment: @srimaln91
No, I haven't

Comment: What sort of hosting solution are you using? Is it managed by someone else?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the Google Cloud Platform, you should have access to the VM. You'll have to "SSH" into the VM and use the command.

```
sudo apt-get install php-imagick
```